Are stances very robust or very fragile?
A follow-up for this question, because the answers were not clear.
(with Remaster we can definetely spend an action to end a stance, but I find the cost too high)
Mountain Stance states:

The only Strikes you can make are falling stone unarmed attacks

There are two ways to read this:

The stance is fragile, if you try to use any other strike, the stance ends
The stance is robust, you cannot even try other types of strikes

Is there any official guidance which it is? If not, what would a native speaker think?

By your definitions, Stances are 'robust'
The text of the Stance trait is:

A stance is a general combat strategy that you enter by using an action with the stance trait, and you remain in for some time. A stance lasts until you get knocked out, until its requirements (if any) are violated, until the encounter ends, or until you use a stance action again, whichever comes first. After you take an action with the stance trait, you can’t take another one for 1 round. You can enter or be in a stance only in encounter mode. You can Dismiss a stance.

The restriction on Strike types is not a requirement. Requirements are listed at the top of a stance. EX:

Disarming Stance
[one-action] Feat 6
[Fighter] [Stance]
Source Player Core pg. 145 2.0
Archetype Duelist*
Prerequisites trained in Athletics
Requirements You are wielding a single one-handed melee weapon and hold nothing else in your hands

Therefore, (trying) to make a non-Stance Strike does not qualify for ending the Stance, and is simply disallowed.
The cases where a Stance ends are:

You become Unconscious
You no longer meet the Requirements (e.g. weapon/armor usage, on the ground, etc)
You use another Stance action
You use an action to Dismiss the stance
The encounter ends

